# Can i read and write on different txt files in a method (contents in the file that im reading gets deleted)?

Tags: java, file-io

I want to make a method that reads a specific .txt file, compares with another specific .txt file that has been assigned to an array, and then if they dont match, write a .txt that prints the issues. Is it possible to write a .txt file while reading from another .txt?
(Note: I am using PrintWriter for writing a file and Scanner for reading a file)

```
public static void updateInventory(String filename1, String filename2, String[] name1, int[] quantity1) {
  File updated = new File(filename1);
  Scanner input = new Scanner(updated);
  File log = new File(filename2);
  PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(log);

  int i = 0;

  while(input.hasNext()) {
     do {
        String s = input.next();
        s = s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        if (s == name1[i]) {
           int num = input.nextInt();
           if (num >= 0 && num < quantity1[i]) {
              quantity1[i] -= num ;
           }               
        }
        i++;
     } while(i < name1.length);

     if (i == name1.length) {
        output.println("ERROR: Item " + s + " not found");
     }

     if (num < 0) {
        output.println("ERROR: Invalid amount requested (" + num + ")");
     }

     input.close();
     output.close();
  }    
}
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: "Is it possible to write a .txt file while reading from another .txt?" -- yes, of course it is possible

Comment: I added the code @Plochie

Comment: After the line _PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(log)_ , it deletes the other file's contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs the following improvement:

1. Use [FileWriter(File file, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) to open the log file in append mode.
2. Use `string1.equals(string2)` instead of `string1==string2` to compare `string1` with `string2`.
3. Use `hasNextInt()` before using `nextInt()`.
4. Use the termination condition for the `while` loop considering all aspects e.g. values which may make it run infinitely and the values which the code inside the `while` loop is using.

Given below is the complete code:

```
public static void updateInventory(String filename1, String filename2, String[] name1, int[] quantity1) {
    File updated = new File(filename1);
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(updated);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file, " + filename1);
    }
    FileWriter log = null;
    PrintWriter output = null;
    try {
        log = new FileWriter(filename2, true);
        output = new PrintWriter(log);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating log file, " + filename2);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    String s;
    while (input != null && input.hasNext() && i < name1.length && i < quantity1.length) {
        s = input.next();
        s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        if (s.equals(name1[i]) && input.hasNextInt()) {
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (num >= 0 && num < quantity1[i]) {
                quantity1[i] -= num;
            }
        }
        if (i == name1.length) {
            output.println("ERROR: Item " + s + " not found");
        }
        if (num < 0) {
            output.println("ERROR: Invalid amount requested (" + num + ")");
        }
        i++;
    }
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

I have already tested this code using some dummy values. Feel free to comment in case you come across any issue while using it.

Comment: when i try to compile it, its giving me the error **error: cannot find symbol** _catch (FileNotFoundException e)_ (^ points the FileNotFoundException)

Comment: also, if i make this with _throws Exception_ instead of try and catchs, would it be okay? Im new to coding and i have never used tries and catches before